# how do you create a US States heatmap based on some values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame called x:

```
dput(tail(x,20))
structure(list(State = structure(c(22L, 58L, 2L, 33L, 75L, 16L, 
26L, 17L, 14L, 76L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 41L, 67L, 31L, 35L, 21L, 20L, 
69L), .Label = c("Texas", "New York", "Florida", "Illinois", 
"Georgia", "Kentucky", "Tennessee", "California", "Alabama", 
"Indiana", "Bayern", "Michigan", "Arizona", "Pennsylvania", "Hawaii", 
"Ohio", "Oregon", "Nairobi Area", "South Carolina", "Wisconsin", 
"West Virginia", "New Jersey", "Maryland", "Colorado", "Missouri", 
"Oklahoma", "District of Columbia", "Minnesota", "Massachusetts", 
"Louisiana", "Virginia", "Connecticut", "North Carolina", "Ile-de-France", 
"Washington", "Sichuan", "Arkansas", "Nevada", "Idaho", "Al Balqa'", 
"Utah", "Maine", "Kansas", "Iowa", "Mississippi", "Ontario", 
"Montana", "New Hampshire", "Nebraska", "Cordoba", "London, City of", 
"Cavite", "Armed Forces Europe, Middle East, & Canada", "Ar Riyad", 
"Quintana Roo", "Zurich", "Lombardia", "New Mexico", "Alberta", 
"Ho Chi Minh", "Cortes", "Delaware", "Distrito Federal", "Ad Dawhah", 
"Distrito Nacional", "Arbil", "Vermont", "Toscana", "Wyoming", 
"Andhra Pradesh", "Puebla", "Marrakech-Tensift-Al Haouz", "Delhi", 
"Beijing", "North Dakota", "Rhode Island"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(152, 3, 926, 20, 1, 167, 26, 25, 51, 1, 6, 13, 
    633, 14, 1, 60, 47, 14, 46, 1), Latitude = c(40.298904, 34.840514, 
    42.165724, 35.630066, 47.52891, 40.388781, 35.565342, 44.57202, 
    40.590752, 41.680893, 33.856893, 35.747845, 31.054487, 40.150032, 
    44.045877, 37.769335, 47.400902, 38.491226, 44.268544, 42.755965
    ), Longitude = c(-74.521013, -106.248483, -74.948052, -79.806417, 
    -99.784012, -82.764916, -96.928919, -122.070939, -77.209755, 
    -71.511782, -80.945011, -86.692343, -97.56346, -111.862433, 
    -72.710689, -78.169968, -121.490493, -80.954452, -89.616509, 
    -107.302488)), .Names = c("State", "Count", "Latitude", "Longitude"
), row.names = 30:49, class = "data.frame")
```

I like to be able to create a map heatmap based on State and Count. I used qplot as below, but no map came up:

```
qplot(Latitude, Longitude, data=x, group=State , fill= Count, geom="polygon")
```

any ideas if I missed something?

Comment: blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html

Comment: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/ggplot2-chloropleth-of-supreme-court-decisions-an-tutorial/  Feels to me like you didn't do much in the way of Google-fu first?

Comment: http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.ie/2013/04/ploting-heatmap-in-map-using-maps.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
x$region <- tolower(x$State)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
states <- map_data("state")
map.df <- merge(states,x, by="region", all.x=T)
map.df <- map.df[order(map.df$order),]
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Count))+
  geom_path()+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)),na.value="grey90")+
  coord_map()
```

Your dataset does not have any map data; it seems to have the centriods for various states along with the counts of something. So first of all you need map data. One source is the `maps` package. The `map_data(...)` function will extract the appropriate map data (e.g., coordinates of the boundary polygons for each state) into a data frame, `states` suitable for use in `ggplot`. `states` has columns `long`, `lat`, `group` and `region`. `region` has the state names (in lower case, unfortunately).

But this isn't enough: we need to associate the counts data in your data frame `x`, with the appropriate state. We do this with `merge(...)` (read the documentation). One issue is that the state names returned by `map_data(...)` are lower case, while your state names are capitalized. So we add a column `region` to your data frame which is just the state names in lower case. Then:

```
map.df <- merge(states,x, by="region", all.x=T)
```

merges the two data frames using the common `region` column. Including `all.x=T` assures that we have the data for all states, even if there is not a row for that state in `x`. Unfortunately `merge(...)` orders the result on the `by=...` column, so we have to re-establish the original order:

```
map.df <- map.df[order(map.df$order),]
```

Now we can plot the map. In the call to `ggplot(...)` we set the default dataset to `map.df` and the x and y aesthetic (horizontal and vertical axes) to `long` and `lat`. Setting the `group` aesthetic assures that states that have more than one polygon (e.g., islands), render properly. `geom_polygon` renders polygons filled based on the `Counts` column in `map.df`. `geom_path()` draws the state boundaries. `scale_fill_gradientn(...)` sets the color palette to the built-in `heat.colors` palette (red-to-yellow), while `rev(...)` reverses the order (so we get yellow-to-red). `na.value=...` sets the color of missing values to a very light grey.

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment

Labeling polygons on a map is always tricky, because some polygons (states in your case) are small and close together, and some are large. That's why maps which are intended to convey quantitative information (choropleth maps or cartograms) almost never do it (here's [an example that does](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OaN24xTMy7U/UJ1rES88aGI/AAAAAAAABE4/GKzZVG-0qZs/s1600/Screen+shot+2012-11-09+at+3.45.10+PM.png), but note what they do in the Northeast). So bottom line, I recommend you leave the state names off.

Having said that, adding them is fairly straightforward, although not especially pretty.

```
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Count))+
  geom_path()+ 
  geom_text(data=x, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude, group=NA, label=State), 
            size=2.5, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.5)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)),na.value="grey90")+
  coord_map()
```

[image]

This adds a text layer with the state names, using `geom_text(...)`. The call to `geom_text(...)` uses you data frame, `x`, (`data=x`), and the latitude and longitude values therein as the location of the labels, and the `State` column for the text itself. Like I said, not pretty...

Comment: how do you put labesl to states?